# visual studio builds with optimization flags even when disabled in options

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I want to use openCV in my Qt project. But the release build crash and mixing release and debug causes bugs. So I made search and found that building openCV on my very computer setting the same flags (optimization flags) that my project may help.

So I used cmake to generate the openCV project, and open the openCV.sln in my visual studio. But even when I disable the optimization in the properties, the detailed log output shows me that there's /O2 in the cl.exe command line.

Any one get a solution? I don't know well how to use Visual Studio, maybe I can build project from command line?

Comment: Near the menu bar you should see a drop down menu that states "Release", change that to "Debug" to disable optimizations.

Comment: @Banex I need to get a RELEASE build but disabling optimization flags. Setting the debug as you suggest will build a debug .lib and that is not what I want.

Comment: Put it to Debug, check the optimizations settings (mostly will be disabled) and then adjust accordingly in Release. I don't have VS right now but it should be under C/C++ and Optimizations.

Comment: When I go to PROJECT > Properties, optimization settings are to "No optimization on the project". I looked for  other settings in VS but did not found anything.